# displaying an image without adding the file format using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i have written a function that can search through a folder and display a picture in a new window if the file is present but i always have to add the image file format or extension before the function can work.

is there a way i can work around ignoring the extension like `.gif` or `.png`

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *

def display_pix():
    hmm   = Toplevel(window)
    hmm.geometry('300x300')
    label = Label(hmm,)
    label.pack()

    PhotoImage(        file = 'C:\\Python34\\' + e.get())
    logo = PhotoImage( file = 'C:\\Python34\\' + e.get()) 
    label.img = logo
    label.config(image = label.img)

 window = Tk()
 e = Entry(  window, width= 20)
 b = Button( window, text = 'search',command = display_pix)
 e.place(x = 50, y = 30)
 b.place(x = 70, y = 50)

 window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean you don't want the user to have to type the extension, and you want your program to look for all possible image files with any extension that match what the user has entered?

Comment: As a side note: use 4 characters for indent, not 1; this makes it very hard to tell what's part of the function and what's outside the function. Especially since I think you've got it wrong—that code from `window = Tk()` to the end almost certainly shouldn't be inside `display_pix()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is named `spam.gif`, that's its filename, so you can't open it as just `spam`. (Yes, Windows Explorer tries to hide this from you, but only to a limited extent—and if you want to do the same thing, you have to do the same thing Windows Explorer does.)

If you want the user to be able to type `spam`, and for your program to automatically open `spam.gif` or `spam.jpg` or `spam.png`, you need to explicitly look for files matching the pattern you want. And you also have to decide what to do if two such files are found, or a file named `spam.txt` that isn't an image at all, or…

The simplest version (just try to open the first `spam.*` that you find) is this:

```
def open_image_file(path, name):
    for fullname in os.listdir(path):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, name + '.*'):
            return PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(path, fullname))
```

Now you can do this:

```
logo = open_image_file(r'C:\Python34', e.get())
```

(If no files named `spam.*` were found, you'll end up with `None`. If, say, a text file or an executable was found and `PhotoImage` raised an exception, you'll get an exception. Otherwise, `logo` will be a `PhotoImage` of the first `spam.*` file.)

Comment: thanks abarnert..but i cant seem to get my way around it..can you pls re-write the code exactly like the way i sent it?...would really appreciate it

Comment: @JoeyDanielDarko: If you're confused by something specific, ask something specific. If you want someone to write your code for you so you don't have to understand how it works, you need to hire a consultant, not ask on StackOverflow.